# Run sha256sum (from Cygwin) on file with special character and blank (quoting does not work)

Tags: powershell, cygwin, sha256

I have Cygwin installed in order to use Linux command line tools on Windows. I also added it to my PATH. In general, it works fine, but I observe this weird behavior:

I want to run `sha256sum` on the file `C:\Users\s1504gl\Desktop\Täst .txt`. Note the german Umlaut `ä` and the whitespace before the file extension. In order to avoid problems with paths, I always quote paths in command line calls, such as:

```
sha256sum "C:\Users\s1504gl\Desktop\Täst .txt"
```

However, PowerShell returns

> /usr/bin/sha256sum: '"C:\Users\s1504gl\Desktop\T'$'\303\244''st .txt"': No such file or directory

When I rename the file to either `Täst.txt` or `Test .txt`, it works. So the combination of the special character `ä` and the whitespace seems to cause the problem. Exchanging double quotes by single quotes does not change anything in this case.

I am pretty sure it has to to with PowerShell since the example works without any problems on my Linux machine.

Is there some other way of escaping special characters and/or blanks that I do not know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following workaround:

I create a temporary file from R, containing all the necessary commands and then run this tempfile using `bash` which is also included in Cygwin. This way, I escape from the problem occurring due to different encodings in Windows and the Linux tools from Cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Run from Cygwin terminal

```
sha256sum "/cygdrive/C/Users/s1504gl/Desktop/Täst\ .txt"
```

In general Cygwin program do not accept Windows paths and works surely with POSIX path

Comment: This returns `sha256sum: '/cygdrive/C/Users/s1504gl/Desktop/Täst\ .txt': No such file or directory`. Anyway, in the Cygwin Terminal works my code from above. But I need a solution that runs in PowerShell or cmd.exe ...